# Calculating value from where it should sit on a graph (line of best fit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, trend, best-fit

I have the following sample dataset -

```
|     a     |    f    |
|-----------|---------|
| £75.00    |  43,200 |
| £500.00   |  36,700 |
| £450.00   |  53,400 |
| £450.00   |  25,700 |
| £250.00   |  12,900 |
| £1,600.00 | 136,000 |
| £600.00   |  72,900 |
| £500.00   |  13,000 |
| £500.00   |  49,600 |
| £500.00   |  43,600 |
| £1,000.00 | 104,000 |
```

And I've used google graphs to create a line of best fit for it

[image]

It has analysed the 'trend line' as `0.762`.

I simply want to create a function that I can use to calculate A, when given F. I just want a number returned.

```
const calc = f => what_A_should_be_given_F
```

---

What might be a good approach for this?

Thanks for any help, Ollie

---

`EDIT:` The slope is `83.81246554`, and the y-intercept is `633.9917215`.

Comment: If `y = mx + b`, you have a slope `m`, do you have `b` as well?

Comment: @MatusDubrava I've just added the slope and intercept - thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

If you have `y = mx + b` and need to get `x` you need to modify your equation to `x = (y - b) / m`

```js
const arr = [43200, 36700, 53400, 25700, 12900, 136000, 72900, 13000, 49600, 43600, 104000];

const m = 83.81246554;
const b = 633.991172215;
const calc = f => (f - b) / m;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${arr[i]} => ${calc(arr[i])}`);
}
```